# how we get url of api

Tags: php, android, json

i made simple api in php the, i run this api in wamp server, i want to connect this api in my android aop. So ho w can i find the url of the api. Or how we connect this api in my app.

here is the link of my api in wamp server.

```
http://localhost/business/allData
```

Below is the sample of my api.

```
$application->get('/allData', function() use($application){
  $db=new dbHandler();
$result=$db->fetchAllData();
header("application/json");

echo json_encode($result);});
```

Comment: Use the IP address of your wamp server

Comment: Wamp has an option to "put online" which exposes your IP as a web server. Use that.

Answer (score 0):

1. First make your Wampserver online with the Put Online option that you access with right click of the server icon.
2. Second go to a website where you have the IP displayed for instance www.whatismyipaddress.com or something like that.
3. If needed then you need to open the port 80 and 443(if you are planning to encrypt in the future) to forward the local router to your local IP inside the network.
4. Call the API like this : http://ip.goes.here.instead/business/allData
5. Optional. Get a domain or a subdomain that you point to this url especially if you are running this APP for long time and your ip change. (I am sure it will at some point)